# Comparing 2d array with 1D array iteration

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays translations(2-dimensional),and line(1-dimensional). translations holds arrays, when ever the index for line and translation[][i] matches i want to print that line bold.otherwise print next line as it is. i have tried it with this code.

```
$translations[0]=array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$translations[1]=array("ferrari", "mustang", "bently");
$lines=array("mustang","BMW");

for($i=0;$i<count($translations);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($translations[$i]);$j++){
        foreach ($lines as $key =>$line){
           if($d==$translation[$i][$j]) {
              echo "<b>" .$translation[$i][$j] . "</b><br>" ;
           }
           else{
              echo $translation[$i][$j]."<br>";
           }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem here is that it prints translation subarrays element 3 times. i know the problem is in the way i am iterating the arrays, how should i fix this problem? help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this will help you out. Instead of looping over `$lines` array, you can just check with `in_array` that whether an element is present or not.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792138)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$translations[0] = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$translations[1] = array("ferrari", "mustang", "bently");
$lines = array("mustang", "BMW");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($translations); $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($translations[$i]); $j++)
    {
        if (in_array($translations[$i][$j], $lines))
        {
            echo "<b>".$translations[$i][$j] ."</b>". PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $translations[$i][$j] .PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a typo, what i want is when i find a match i want to print the line/text in bold, otherwise the line should be printed as it is hence the use of else.

Comment: @MuhammadImran No issues my current post will help you achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to print all the elements in translations **only once** with those matching with lines in bold while the rest as it is, your code prints only those that matches.

Comment: Do you want to print matching with bold and non-matching as normal and print only once?

Comment: yes. the code works but its printing more than once.

Comment: @MuhammadImran i have updated my post you can check that one.